# Manipulate select multiple

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to make it happen that when *folder 2* is selected it also selects it's subs *subfolder* 2a and *subfolder 2aa*

[image]

Comment: Please provide some HTML code as well, a picture doesn't tell us much.

Comment: you can implement it only with javascript. can you show your html-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are creating folder list, you must keep two fields, one for checking if the item is it self a parent, and second field for , if it is child then who is its Parent. So when use clicks a parent it loop through list and then finds item who are its child, where it matches, just change "selected" to true.
For loop you can use javascript.